# Browse and run selected installed Application for Android/UWP/IOs with Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin, uwp

I am trying to make an application that can **find the device-installed applications**. **Select** the desired application **and** then **run** it. I've done my research and can't really find a proper way for neither. I **have made** a opendialog-style with `FilePicker` , **but it does not work the way I want**. **On UWP** I can select the desired .exe but with `Process.Start` it does not start successfully ( looks likes it tries to open, **but silently closes** ). **On Android** **I can't** really **target** the .apk of **the installed application**.

I am looking for a cross-platform application . **Is it possible** and **right**? **Should I** stay with the cross-platform logic or is it better to **make separate apps for each operating system ?**

Comment: This just isn't going to work.  On iOS specifically you can just url schemes to open other apps, but you can't specifically pick and choose apps to open.

Comment: Couldn't I break it into sections for each device. For example , if UWP ... if Android .. etc ? Does it make sense, for a cross-platform app or just make separate applications ?

Comment: @ehem cross-platform or make separate application, it depends on you. About your problem, jason has replied to you.

Comment: Can you direct me to a working method, for running apps in android using c#?